# How to pass stopOnFailure option to WebDriver from Jasmine API?

Tags: jasmine, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am executing my Jasmine JS tests using WebDriver. Because I am not executing the tests using Jasmine itself, I cannot pass in command line arg:

```
jasmine --stop-on-failure=true
```

Is there any other option to pass this argument to WebDriver? Maybe in the onPrepare function, but I cannot find a public API in Jasmine to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the option by [setting `bail` to 1](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/wdio.conf.js#L109), either in your configuration file or through the command line.